# Showing missing dependencies while deploying an application in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jpa, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

Getting following exception while deploying the ear file whose structure as follow :

Ear comprise of ejb module(EJB + JPA) and war module

```
    //stack trace
    11:47:09,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) 
    JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version  
    9.0)
    11:47:09,290 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering 
    web context: /saleshout
    11:47:09,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) 
    JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SaleShoutEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back 
    with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" 
    => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"SaleShoutEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/nsqejb-0.0.1-
    SNAPSHOT.jar#persistence\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.
    SMSCampaignDataSourceMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"SaleShoutEar-0.0.1- 
    SNAPSHOT.ear/nsqejb-0.0.1-
    SNAPSHOT.jar#persistence\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.SMSCampaignDataSource]"]}
    11:47:10,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1)  
    JBAS015877: Stopped deployment nsqejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in 45ms
    11:47:10,039 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) 
    JBAS015877: Stopped deployment saleshout-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in 74ms
    11:47:10,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) 
    JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SaleShoutEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear in 126ms
    11:47:10,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) 
    JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
    service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.SMSCampaignDataSource (missing) dependents: 
    [service jboss.persistenceunit."SaleShoutEar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/nsqejb-0.0.1-
    SNAPSHOT.jar#persistence"]
```

To integrate ejb with JPA i follow this link http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-ejb3-jpa-project-in-eclipse-jboss-as-7-1/

I have configured the datasource but still getting persistence.xml related exception.
I am new to JBoss.can anyone tell me why i am getting this exception.

```
    //Persistence.xml
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/SMSCampaignDataSource</jta-data-source>
     <class>...</class>
 <properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
      value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"></property>
  <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>      
     </properties>
     </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `SMSCampaignDataSource Missing`. You had probably declared it as a jta data source in your `persistence.xml` but didn't configure it yourself.

Comment: and where is the exception. I can see only a bunch of useless (for us) logs

Comment: @Orid I have configured the datasource.Please see the updated post.Thanks

Comment: You have declared a persistence unit but you haven't defined the data source which it uses. That is: you've configured Hibernate, but not the Postgres connection. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the datasource in the standalone.xml and if you have already defined  then please see whether your added datasource is saved or not.The stack trace clearly indicate that the problem is with datasource as persistence.xml is fine.I have face the same situation but in my case the changes that i have made in the standalone.xml was not getting saved as the JBoss directory was having the root privilege.So i edited and added the datasource in the standalone.xml with root privilege and the problem resolved of missing dependencies.

If your's is the different case then this link might help you : [Services with missing/unavailable dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268141/services-with-missing-unavailable-dependencies)